# CSS table position in Firefox not same in IE

Tags: css, html-table

I have a question about table position in Firefox and IE 8,9.

My table display in IE isn't same with Firefox after I submit something message in textarea.
Here it's the screenshot of my page:

[image]

The black circle is to show the table in Firefox position is ok.

[image]

The 2nd image is to show the table in IE position is ok.

[image]

Now I try to share something message like the 3rd images. After submit, the table position is going out from the div line.
The HTML Code :

```
<table class="t_feed" cellspacing="10">
<td class="td_haps">
</td>
</table>
```

The css code:

```
.t_feed
{
width: 600px;
margin-left: -20px;
}

.td_haps
{
padding: 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
border-top-right-radius:5px;
background:#fff;
border: 1px;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-color: #e8e9eb;
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-color: #e8e9eb;
border-right-style: solid;
border-right-color: #e8e9eb;
}
```

So, what's the idea for solve this problem ?

Comment: What happens if you do not subtract the 20 pixels?

Comment: This little code snippet is an improvement, but it's still not enough. E.G. are you mixing measurements like pixels and points, do you have a standards-mode-triggering doctype, etc. Please provide a link to the actual site.

Comment: You forgot your <tr> before the <td> .Your code is invalid.